# Hash at the end of a URL changes page layout?

Tags: html, css, hash

Is there any reason that would cause something like page.html and page.html#sectionid to have different layouts?

I am having this problem with http://mintclean.ca/new/about-mintclean/ and http://mintclean.ca/new/about-mintclean/#difference, which technically speaking should be the exact same page, with one just starting more scrolled down. However, the second has a white gap under the footer while the first does not.

I can't for the life for me figure out what is happening--the problem is completely consistent across browsers. Any help in understanding what's going on would be much appreciated!

Comment: Please do not link to your site. Read: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to clear the floats inside your `<footer>` so after the `.site-info f3` class, also add `padding-bottom: 0;` to your `<footer>`. I think this should do it.

I see you have `clear: both;` applied to the footer but this is not clearing the elements within.